# Do ADrive.com have an API?

Tags: .net, cloud, storage

Sorry for my English first.

I want to write an .net application to store file on ADrive.com cloud storage.
I can't find any document about ADrive.com API.

Do ADrive.com have an API? If they have one, how can i get it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API from ADrive.com. In my opinion, it is just a cloud storage service and they try to get their software AND service to their customers on their own.

As you may know, their software available to all popular platform.